# Функция повторно не выполняется

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Я создаю игру.При нажатии пробела должен спавниться бот в рандомном месте, но если я нажимаю на пробел повторно, то функция не выполняется

```py
import random
import pygame

GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

widht = 11
height = 11
FPS = 40

# создание спрайта водорослей
class tree():
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((widht, height))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(1, 1200)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(1, 900)
        self.G = random.randint(10, 100)
    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, (x, y, widht, self.height))

    def update(self):
        self.G += 10

# Создаем игру и окно
pygame.init()  # экран игры
pygame.mixer.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 900))
pygame.display.set_caption("Evolucion")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
trees = pygame.sprite.Group()
tree = tree()
trees.add_internal(tree)

def spawnt():
    all_sprites.add_internal(tree)
    trees.add_internal(tree)


# Цикл игры
run = True
while run:

    pygame.time.delay(50)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    spawnt()

    all_sprites.update()

    win.fill((255, 255, 255))
    all_sprites.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас по крайней мере две ошибки.

Во-первых, у вас имя `tree` используется и как название класса, и как имя переменной для конкретного экземпляра. Так делать нельзя, им нужно дать разные имена. Обычно имя класса пишут с большой буквы, и я рекомендую придерживаться этого стандарта.

Вторая ошибка в том, что вы один раз создаёте один объект класса, и потом пытаетесь много раз тот же самый объект добавить на поле. Но это тот же самый объект, и у него будут те же самые координаты, так что сколько бы вы не нажимали пробел, объект будет в том же самом месте.

Вам нужно каждый раз создавать новый объект при вызове функции `spawnt`.

Таким образом, с учётом моих исправлений, ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```
import random
import pygame

GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

widht = 11
height = 11
FPS = 40


# создание спрайта водорослей
class Tree():                                             # Исправил здесь

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((widht, height))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(1, 1200)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(1, 900)
        self.G = random.randint(10, 100)

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, (x, y, widht, self.height))

    def update(self):
        self.G += 10

# Создаем игру и окно
pygame.init()  # экран игры
pygame.mixer.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 900))
pygame.display.set_caption("Evolucion")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
trees = pygame.sprite.Group()
#tree = tree()                                            # Убрал эти две строчки
#trees.add_internal(tree)

def spawnt():
    tree = Tree()                                         # И добавил эту строчку
    all_sprites.add_internal(tree)
    trees.add_internal(tree)


# Цикл игры
run = True
while run:

    pygame.time.delay(50)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    spawnt()

    all_sprites.update()

    win.fill((255, 255, 255))
    all_sprites.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: мен пишет:TypeError: update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: @IvanBerkut, пишет именно в том коде, который привёл я, или вы его меняли?

Comment: Я  уже исправил код